# Autofac Named Registration Failing

Tags: c#, autofac

I am trying to used named registrations and a func to register an implementation I need.

```
 builder
       .RegisterType<AImpl>().Named<IMyInterface>("all");

        builder
       .RegisterType<BImpl>().Named<IMyInterface>("all");

        builder
            .Register(c =>
            {
                var myImpl= c.ResolveNamed<IEnumerable<IMyInterface>>("all").FirstOrDefault(a => a.Code == "SOMESTRING");
                if (myImpl== null)
                    throw new MySpecificException("SOMESTRING");
                return myImpl;
            })
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

I get the following exception when i try resolve:

```
        var myImpl = c.Resolve<IMyInterface>();
```

> An exception of type 'Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException' occurred in Autofac.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The requested service
>   'MyNameSpace.IMyInterface' has not
>   been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component
>   to provide the service, check for service registration using
>   IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an
>   optional dependency.

Anyone any idea why this is failing? The inner func resolves do work correctly so it isnt that!

Thanks
Neil

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I do not understand the question, but I think you're doing it wrong. RegisterNamed should be used in order to get an implementation by a string tag.

In your example you have:

```
builder.RegisterType<AImpl>().Named<IMyInterface>("all");
builder.RegisterType<BImpl>().Named<IMyInterface>("all");
```

This doesn't make sense to me.
You should call something like:

```
builder.RegisterType<AImpl>().Named<IMyInterface>("TheNameIsA");
builder.RegisterType<BImpl>().Named<IMyInterface>("TheNameIsB");
```

And, in the consuming class, you can require in the constructor an:

```
public MyComponent(IIndex<string, IMyInterface> myInterfaceIndex)
...
```

and require from it the component you want as:

```
var a = myInterfaceIndex["TheNameIsA"];
var b = myInterfaceIndex["TheNameIsB"];
```

Alternatively, you can require (via constructor or property injection) an ILifetimeScope and use it for dynamic resolution as:

```
var a = myLifetimeScope.ResolveNamed<IMyInterface>("TheNameIsA");
```

Note, unrelated to the question:
This, obviously, if you REALLY need to have more than one implementation available simultaneously.
If you need only one of the two, you should use a Module and configure it so it will register only one of the two implementations.

Edit:
The exception you are getting is (should be) because you are not calling ResolveNamed. You are asking for a IMyInterface, but you didn't registered an IMyInterface without name. So you get the exception. I'm not 100% confident, but I dare to say I'm pretty confident about this.